# How to insert values to a list collection

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, entity-framework

I need to insert elements into my empty list collection as one array item that contains Card and Date.

TimeOut Justification is my entity class that contains parameters like Card and Date

I'm checking if TimeOutArray is 0, then i need to insert Card and Date.

```
List<TimeOutJustification>TimeOutArray;
```

Result should look like this

```
[0] = {Card="1234",Date="12-03-19"};
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please update your post to include what you have tried, what isn't working and expected output for us to help you? Also please post the definition of `TimeOutJustification`.

Comment: `list.Add(new TimeOutJustification {Card="1234",Date="12-03-19"});`

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani maybe, from the post above it's `null`, that code will throw up...

Comment: that's why i added as comment. OP is not talking about errors, but how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super clear to me what the scenario is here, but I am going to assume that the list `TimeOutArray` may or may not have been initialized, and may or may not have items. It sounds like you want to check for those things, and, if it does not have items, add one.

First, initialize the list if it is null:

```
if (TimeOutArray == null)
{
    TimeOutArray = new List<TimeOutJustification>();
}
```

Then, check if the item count is 0, and add the new item.

```
if (TimeOutArray.Count == 0)
{
    TimeOutArray.Add(new TimeOutJustification
    {
        Card = "1234",
        Date = "12-03-19"
    });
}
```